# Best high concurrency Python / Redis server

Tags: python, performance, redis, bottle

I'm prototyping a Python/Redis based API and am serving JSON using Bottle but unfortunately out of the box Bottle performs badly under load and under high concurrency. Some initial testing on real traffic results in the python script crashing without terminating, which means the API is unresponsive and not restarting*.

What is currently the best solution to scale a Python/Redis API in terms of performance as well as documentation. I find the bottle+greenlet solution poorly documented and not easy to implement for a Python beginner like me. I heard tornado is good but that its integration with Redis is slower than Bottle's.

*Seems that when bottle is unable to send the body of the HTTP request to the client, the server will bug out with "[Errno 32] Broken pipe" errors, which seems like a bad reason for a server to stop working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already read the [Bottle docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#server-options) on this subject?

Bottle performs very well under heavy load--I use it to handle millions of requests per day--but you *mustn't use its default HTTP server* if you need concurrency or high performance.  (By default, Bottle just uses `wsgiref.WSGIServer`, which is single-threaded and not meant for any high-perf application.)

In production, I run Bottle in Apache with [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).  ([Here's an example](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial_app.html#server-setup) of that.)  Scales extremely well; Bottle itself adds negligible overhead.

In other words: your performance bottleneck is not caused by Bottle, it's caused by your HTTP server.  Choose a scalable server and you'll see better performance.

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT 2015**

I've discovered that Bottle has its limits, and for greater concurrency (thousands of QPS per core), Bottle won't do.  (The bottleneck seems to be an interaction between Bottle's use of thread local storage and gevent's TLS implementation.)  I'm not using `falcon` and it's performing much better at high loads than Bottle could.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized Bottle was complementary to servers like cherrypy rather than an alternative. Seems like my solution might be as easy as 'pip install cherrypy' and adding server='cherrypy' to my script. I'll also see if the script fares well behind my apache+varnish website infrastructure

Comment: I benchmarked about 10 servers and ended up running Tornado. Both cherrypy and tornado are very fast but Tornado seems to be more stable under high concurrency/load

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner you should not start with evented (twisted/tornado/gevent/eventlet...) libs.

It will lead you to place you dont know!

If you need to scale add machines and balance the load with a load balancer.

Comment: The API is just a single 200 line file I'm sure I can figure out the async stuff if I'm provided with some good examples, preferably using Redis in an async fashion

Comment: Although I agree evented stuff can be very difficult to sift through this is really poor advice. There are simple and cost effective ways to scale python webservers that don't involve more machines. Although, sometimes you do need _better_ machines.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the particular requirements of your application, you might benefit from trying my implementation of a [multithreaded Python WSGIServer](https://github.com/RonRothman/mtwsgi).  ([Here's its page](http://ronrothman.com/public/leftbraned/mtwsgi-a-multithreaded-python-wsgi-implementation/) on my own blog.)

It's a drop-in replacement for `wsgiref.WSGIServer`, so you can use it with Bottle with minimal changes.

Basically, it's a bit like Apache's `worker` MPM (but with one process): each request will be handled by its own thread from a pool of N preallocated threads.

I've found it useful in the case where I want concurrency in my Bottle app, but where I prefer not to use Apache or bring in any other significant server dependencies.

Here's an example:

```
import bottle
import time

app = bottle.Bottle()

@app.route('/')
def foo():
    time.sleep(2)
    return 'hello, world!\n'

app.run(server=MTServer, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, thread_count=3)

# Here, app is nonblocking; it will handle up to 3 requests concurrently.
# A 4th concurrent request would block until one of the first 3 completed.
```

Please let me know if you give it a try, and how it worked.  (Suggestions and contributions are welcome.  Thanks!)

(Adding this as a separate answer because it's somewhat more radical than my previous answer.)